# Columns/Grid CSS does not work correctly on IE/Edge, cannot find proper documentation

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge, css-grid

Site: https://alexis-drakopoulos.com/

My columns work in Firefox and Chrome, but not IE or Edge. I tried pixels, percentages and `fr`, but nothing works) I also have a .wrapper2 which is identical for later use.

I tried adding the .iea and .ieb classes, but it's still not working:

```css
.wrapper { 
    display: grid;
    display: -ms-grid;
    grid-template-columns: 40% 60%;
    -ms-grid-columns: 500px 500px;
}
.iea {
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
}
.ieb {
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="logotop logopad">
        <div class="column iea"><img src="images/FRsmall.png" alt="FRsmall" width="160" height="160" align="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="logotop">
        <div class="column ieb">
            <h1 style="padding-left:2%">
                <a href="index.html"><span2><span1 class="black-text yellow-hover">Alexis <span class='green-text'>Drakopoulos</span></span1></span2></a>
            </h1>
            <hr width="37%">
            <ul style="padding-left:0">
            <h3>
                <a href="projects.html"><span class="black-text projects">{Projects}</span></a>
                <a href="blog.html"><span class="black-text green-hover">{Blog}</span></a>
                <a href="cv.html"><span class="black-text greentext-hover">{CV}</span></a>
                <a href="contact.html"><span class="black-text green-hover">{Contact}</span></a>
            </h3>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is "not working". Column width? Column count?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45786788/3597276

Comment: I have no idea what isn't working, on edge the site elements are all over the place as though it's ignoring my column statements.

Comment: @FitnessRegiment regarding Michael's duplicate, what build of Windows 10 do you have? Have you received the Windows Fall Creator update yet? That update brought a change to how Edge supports CSS Grids.

Comment: I have Version 1703 build 15063.674. So wait does it work for you? It doesn't work at all for me. Also now for some reason my contact page doesn't have ssl :(

Comment: oh god I updated and now it nearly works, a couple of elements are iffy but thanks!