# Internet Explorer display grid and grid-template-columns

Tags: css, internet-explorer, grid, css-grid

I have the following

```
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));

display:-ms-grid;
```

How do I get the -ms-grid-columns to work the same way?

Internet Explorer does not recognize `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr))`.

Comment: Do other browsers recognise it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Grid Layout not working in Edge and IE 11 even with -ms prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786788/css-grid-layout-not-working-in-edge-and-ie-11-even-with-ms-prefix)