# CSS Grid with IE11 specs - grid collapses on itself

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-grid

I'm having an issue getting the CSS grid to work. As far as I know, I am following the spec for the IE10/11 specification for this. My initial research led me to: [CSS Grid Layout not working in Edge and IE 11 even with -ms prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786788/css-grid-layout-not-working-in-edge-and-ie-11-even-with-ms-prefix) - and tried implementing suggested changes.

my code is below:

```css
.filter-item-grid {
 display: grid;
 display: -ms-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  -ms-grid-columns: 267px 267px;
  -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-item-grid">
  <div class="letter-list__filter-item">
      <h3 class="letter-list__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Headline</a>
      </h3>
      <p>Sub headline</p>
   </div>
   <div class="letter-list__filter-item">
      <h3 class="letter-list__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Headline</a>
      </h3>
      <p>Sub headline</p>
    </div>
    <div class="letter-list__filter-item">
      <h3 class="letter-list__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Headline</a>
      </h3>
      <p>Sub headline</p>
    </div>
    <div class="letter-list__filter-item">
      <h3 class="letter-list__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Headline</a>
      </h3>
      <p>Sub headline</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When viewing this markup in IE, it looks as if everything is absolutely positioned in the same spot. As per the attached answer I'm:

1. Using vendor prefixes
2. not relying on `auto` for the MS fallback
3. Not using `repeat()`
4. explicitly stating position of each item.

What specifically needs to change to fully support the IE specification for CSS grid? Or is it reccomended to use the `@supports` CSS query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the display setting `to display: grid -ms-grid;` and adding the `new` class to each makes it not collapse see snippet:
Tested in IE11 and Chrome v67.0.3396.99.

```css
.filter-item-grid {
  display: grid -ms-grid;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2; 
}
.new{
vertical-align: top;
padding-top:10px;
margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-item-grid">
  <div class="letter-list__filter-item new">
    <h3 class="letter-list__filter-title new">
      <a href="#">Headline</a>
    </h3>
    <p>Sub headline</p>
  </div>
  <div class="letter-list__filter-item new">
    <h3 class="letter-list__filter-title new">
      <a href="#">Headline</a>
    </h3>
    <p>Sub headline</p>
  </div>
  <div class="letter-list__filter-item new">
    <h3 class="letter-list__filter-title new">
      <a href="#">Headline</a>
    </h3>
    <p>Sub headline</p>
  </div>
  <div class="letter-list__filter-item new">
    <h3 class="letter-list__filter-title new">
      <a href="#">Headline</a>
    </h3>
    <p>Sub headline</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It just puts everything into one column - I need to maintain the grid layout.

Comment: Edited to maintain columns but it is putting some weird white space above first column still working on it.

Comment: Take a look at that.

Comment: do you have a <main> element anywhere on your page? use Modernizer.js to force IE to use block rendering or use a div instead of <main> eg. <div id="main" role="main">

Comment: @RobParsons great tip! No, I do not but I'll remember this in the future.

Comment: @kawnah did you look at the updated edit it now matches your example in IE