# Avoid overlapping item with CSS grid (in IE11)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, css-grid

I've the simplest CSS Grid possible

```
.grid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 50% 50%;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/nisizebewi/1/edit), a working example.

On major browser, it works as expected but in Internet Explorer 11, the grid elements are overlapping.

Is there a way (without turning them to flex) to fix that issue on IE11 ?

Comment: Have you found a solution for your Problem yet? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunatly no ... I had to go back to flex https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-in-ie-faking-an-auto-placement-grid-with-gaps/

Comment: same problem here

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45786788/3597276

Answer (score 2):

The problem basically boils down to the fact that IE doesn't do auto-placement like every other browser.  Unless you tell it where you want each element within the grid, it will assume you want everything in column 1 row 1.  If this is a dynamic website you are better off with flexbox.  If its like your example and you know where each element is to go then you have to say so like so:

```css
.grid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 50% 50%;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cell:first-of-type{
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

.cell:last-of-type{
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">a</div>
  <div class="cell">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;b</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

All that being said if you really need IE support you should probably stick to flexbox.  They just do not get along.

UPDATE:
I recently stumbled upon an article outlining how Autoprefixer, if set up correctly, will do the grunt work for you if you are doing a grid-template-areas sort of thing. still no auto-placement but it does save you some time if you are making a template and are placing the elements anyway.
[Read This Article](https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-in-ie-duplicate-area-names-now-supported/)