# How to rewrite CSS Grid declaration w/ grid areas for IE11

Tags: css, layout, grid, css-grid

I have a handy Container component that defines a grid that wraps all children within the middle column, which serves as a max-width container. This component has the option of specifying the child item to break that max-width container and start at the first column and end at the last column.

See this blog post for further explanation: https://cloudfour.com/thinks/breaking-out-with-css-grid-layout/

See this Codepen for example: 
https://codepen.io/tylersticka/full/wdmymG/

I was confident that'd the old IE 10 and IE 11 spec would have properties to cover the newer spec's properties but I haven't had any luck with in when testing in IE 11. What syntax am I missing or do I need to modify to replicate grid-areas in IE 11?

```
.grid-container {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;

  -ms-grid-columns: [full-start] minmax(0, 1fr) [main-start] minmax(0, 1120px) [main-end] minmax(0, 1fr)
[full-end];

  grid-template-columns:
    [full-start] minmax(0, 1fr) [main-start] minmax(0, 1120px) [main-end] minmax(0, 1fr) [full-end];

  > * {
    grid-column: main;
    padding: 0 16px;
  }
}

.full-width {
  grid-column: full;
}
```

Sources:

https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-in-ie-debunking-common-ie-grid-misconceptions/

https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-in-ie-css-grid-and-the-new-autoprefixer/

https://autoprefixer.github.io/

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45786788/3597276