# IE11 Grid Template

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, css-grid

Iam working on a simple layout. It works on edge and co, but in IE11 it places anything in the first row.

```
<body>
  <div class="sidebar1">
    <nav>
    <ul>
    </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
  <article class="content">

  </article>
</body>


body {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 250px 1fr;
    -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
}
.sidebar1 {
    -ms-grid-row:1;
    -ms-grid-column:1;
}
.content {
    -ms-grid-row:1;
    -ms-grid-column:2;
}
```

Greetings
Ron

Comment: Have you reviewed this post? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45786788/3597276

Comment: I tested with the code snippet you providing and the test results seem the same in IE and Chrome. Here is my [test sample](https://jsfiddle.net/yuzhou0602/8zwe35kd/4/) you can also try and the [result in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSwjx.png) is like this and the [result in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbX7L.png) is like this. Could you please provide [a minimal sample which can reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the issue?

Comment: So, after I tried ur test sample and it didnt work I found the solution in the browser settings. The standart document mode was set to 5. After I changed it to 11 the code worked fine.

Comment: Then you could post the solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.