# Display grid and grid template css property not working in IE 11 browser

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser

Both the below code is working fine in chrome and firefox.
In IE 11 is   not working .

display grid is not working in IE. Any suggestions ?

```
 .table-content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 45px 80px repeat(6, 30px);

}

.table-points {
    grid-template-columns: 80px repeat(auto-fit, minmax(40px, 1fr));
    display: grid;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Grid Layout not working in IE11 even with prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786788/css-grid-layout-not-working-in-ie11-even-with-prefixes)
The repeat() function doesn't exist in the older spec, so it isn't supported by IE11.

Answer (score 0):

Check browsers support here to know what will be supported or not:
https://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Reference link, hope it helps: https://medium.com/@elad/supporting-css-grid-in-internet-explorer-b38669e75d66

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, IE does not have auto-flow of grid elements. We could assign a specific grid position to each grid element, please check the following sample:

```
<style>
    .container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: 150px 50px;
        grid-gap: 1vw;
        display: -ms-grid;
        /* also faking 1vw grid-gap */
        -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1vw 1fr 1vw 1fr 1vw 1fr;
        /* also faking 1vw grid-gap */
        -ms-grid-rows: 100px 1vw 100px;
    }

    .grid-item {
        /* style just for demo */
        background-color: yellow;
    }

        /* Explicit placement for IE */
        /* Omitting default value of -ms-grid-column: 1 and -ms-grid-row: 1 where possible */
        .grid-item:nth-child(2) {
            -ms-grid-column: 3;
        }

        .grid-item:nth-child(3) {
            -ms-grid-column: 5;
        }

        .grid-item:nth-child(4) {
            -ms-grid-column: 7;
        }

        .grid-item:nth-child(5) {
            -ms-grid-row: 3;
        }

        .grid-item:nth-child(6) {
            -ms-grid-row: 3;
            -ms-grid-column: 3;
        }

        .grid-item:nth-child(7) {
            -ms-grid-row: 3;
            -ms-grid-column: 5;
        }

        .grid-item:nth-child(8) {
            -ms-grid-row: 3;
            -ms-grid-column: 7;
        }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid-item">1,1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">1,2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">1,3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">1,4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">2,1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">2,2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">2,3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">2,4</div>
</div>
```

The result (IE 11 browser):

[image]

Besides, I think you could also consider to use [Bootstrap Grid system](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp), it supports IE11, Microsoft Edge, Firefox and Chrome browser.