# aligning of 5 boxes using flex is giving spacing issue

Tags: html, css

I've been working with grid layout, it's working fine in all browsers except in IE
[Issue with grid layout in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65808164/issue-with-grid-layout-in-ie11)

Now i've been trying the same structure with flex 3 cols * 2 rows but somehow it is not getting as expected because of spaces for the last 2 boxes.

Hope you can help me out with your suggestions either in the grid issue [Issue with grid layout in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65808164/issue-with-grid-layout-in-ie11)

or with the flex

```css
.grid_container{
    margin: 10px auto;
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;    
    display: -moz-box;       
    display: -ms-flexbox;    
    display: -webkit-flex;   
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow: wrap;
}

.box-item {
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.box-item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.box-text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
.box-item {
  width: 45%;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
.box-item {
  width: 90%;
}
}


/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {

}

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
}

/* Tablets potrait----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
}

/* Tablets (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

}

/*--------@media only screen and (min-width: 992px){ } ----------- */

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px) {

}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1400px) {

}
```

```html
<div class="grid_container">
 <div class="box-item">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/255/200/200.jpg?hmac=IYQV36UT5-F1dbK_CQXF7PDfLfwcnwKijqeBCo3yMlc" />
  <div class="box-text">
   dummy text
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box-item">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/255/200/200.jpg?hmac=IYQV36UT5-F1dbK_CQXF7PDfLfwcnwKijqeBCo3yMlc" />
  <div class="box-text">
   dummy text
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box-item">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/255/200/200.jpg?hmac=IYQV36UT5-F1dbK_CQXF7PDfLfwcnwKijqeBCo3yMlc" />
  <div class="box-text">
   dummy text
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box-item">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/255/200/200.jpg?hmac=IYQV36UT5-F1dbK_CQXF7PDfLfwcnwKijqeBCo3yMlc" />
  <div class="box-text">
   dummy text
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box-item">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/255/200/200.jpg?hmac=IYQV36UT5-F1dbK_CQXF7PDfLfwcnwKijqeBCo3yMlc" />
  <div class="box-text">
   dummy text
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @tony_92. CSS new features like flexbox and CSS grid are not supported in IE browser. Any particular reason u want it for IE? One solution would be using floats

Comment: Hi @RohanShenoy, actually in chrome also while using flexbox last 2 elements getting space since i've used space-around but i want to have 5 boxes 3 on top 2 on below leaving last box empty

Comment: I suggest you to use bootstrap, it will give you the desired behavior.

Comment: @tony_92. Got it. Please try my solution. If thats not what ur looking for please let me know and I will update it

Answer (score 0):

You may add this to the css which mimics flex display fo IE:

```
_:-ms-lang(x),
      .ie10up {
        /* IE10+ CSS styles go here */
        .grid_container {
          margin: 10px auto;
          max-width: 1100px;
          width: 100%;
          height: auto;
          display: inline-table;
        }
        .box-item {
          position: relative;
          display: inline;
          text-align: center;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your exiting one. Please update the width to take 1/3 of total width. Also add max-width so that it doesn't exceed that width.

```
.box-item {
    width: 33%;
    max-width: 33%; 
}
```

[image: Result of the above will be]

Comment: Hi @Rohan-shenoy i tried the same. but it's not giving the thing

Comment: Hi @tony_92. Please access this demo link : https://codepen.io/rohanshenoy96/pen/dypLWre