# Live Sass Compiler does not correctly prefix VSCode

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

I use this extension: [Live Sass Compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass). The problem occurs in this value: `repeat(auto-fill, 230px)`, for IE it tries to bring as `-ms-grid-columns: (230px)[auto-fill];`, which it swears at:
[image]

*I use a translator, I hope you understand.*

Comment: You're using a deprecated version of Live Sass Complier, try to use [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=glenn2223.live-sass) instead.

Comment: Thanks, but now it doesn't want to put `-ms-grid-columns`, my settings are `"liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": ["last 10000 versions", "IE 10", "IE 11"]`

Comment: Ahem, I realized that IE does not support repeat(), how can it be replaced?

Comment: I guess it depends on the layout you want, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45787093/9718056).

Comment: My example uses auto-fill.

Comment: I don't know if autoprefixer can be configured to fix that so you might have to write it yourself.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53427229/9718056), your autoprefixer is already doing the job.

Comment: Can you post your comment with the version of the extension, so I can mark it as a solution?

Comment: Yes sure but I will mark it as duplicate instead because I already answered another question with that. Did you find the correct configuration for autoprefixer?

Comment: I think so, but the last question is probably a little off topic. My `--test: color.scale(#036, $lightness: -30%);` is not working. Why?