# CSS Grid auto repeat columns flexbox alternative for IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-grid

I have the following layout on my website

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(350px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: max-content;
}

.item{
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
</div>
```

basically some cards that scale according to device width so there could be 1 card on each row or 10 cards on a row, and they wrap accordingly at the bottom (stay the same width) as shown in my snippet

Now this works **great** except in IE11 (I dont have to support any previous versions). What are my options here? Am I able to do anything similar with flexbox? I know I could specify the widths of each card and have a bunch of media queries.. but I'd rather not.. hoping for a better solution.

**EDIT**

So after a quick play around I was able to come up with a similar solution..

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item{
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 350px;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
</div>
```

but as you can see the last items in the row stretch the entire width of the row when I want them to stay the same width as the rest of the cards, I know that the min-width of the card should be `350px` - but the `max-width` could be as much as the screen allows before it wraps so I cant specify `max-width`

**EDIT 2**

this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744164/flex-box-align-last-row-to-grid) mentions using a psuedo element like so

```
.container::after{
  content: '';
  flex: auto;
}
```

but it doesnt really work now I have seen some solutions that rely on the width of the browser, but I have a collapsable sidebar that alters the width of that parent container so I am unable to rely on the screen width.. which is why that grid solution was so good

**EDIT**

I was able to create a real hacky fix by just adding extra 'invisible' items with the same `flex: 1` and a `height: 0`

Comment: Avoid using the `flex` shorthand property in IE. https://stackoverflow.com/q/32239549/3597276

Answer (score 1):

I try to test your example with IE 11 and made some tests with it.

Than I try to set flex like this **flex: flex: 0 0 33.3333%;;** in **item** class make it work in IE 11.

Modified code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
.container{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.item{
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 350px;
  flex: flex: 0 0 33.3333%;;

  min-width: 350px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

Comment: unfortunately this does not work as expected since I want the squares to fill up the full width of the browser (notice the gap you have shown between the last red box in the top row)

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked this

Use the -ms-grid-row and -ms-grid-column properties.

[CSS Grid auto placement in IE/EDGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45436398/css-grid-auto-placement-in-ie-edge) 
[CSS Grid not working in ie11 despite prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57004310/css-grid-not-working-in-ie11-despite-prefixes) 
https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-grid-layout-20110407/#automatic-placement-of-grid-items

[CSS Grid Layout not working in IE11 even with prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786788/css-grid-layout-not-working-in-ie11-even-with-prefixes)
May help you

Comment: Yeah unfortunately this doesnt work specifically `repeat()` is not supported in IE11 at  all

Comment: OK, let me check alternatives.